# Kerberos 5 Tacking on Realm Twice to Principal

Tags: fedora, kerberos

I recently updated a Fedora 22 workstation and SSSD logins began to fail.

Logs look good until sss_send_pac fails. Oddly the principal user is getting the domain added twice. For example:

```
jgiotta\@magic.local@magic.local
```

I'm not sure what debuggin steps to take at this point. Joining the realm and performing ldapsearch commands are all successful.

Authentication is provided by an Active Directory system on a larger Windows-based network.

When I step up logging output in sssd.conf to level 10 I can review the krb5_child.log. I find the following failure in the log:

> (Thu Dec 3 09:22:36 2015) [[sssd[krb5_child[2158]]]] [sss_send_pac]
>   (0x0040): sss_pac_make_request failed [-1][2]
>
> (Thu Dec 3 09:22:36
>   2015) [[sssd[krb5_child[2158]]]] [validate_tgt] (0x0040): sss_send_pac
>   failed, group membership for user with principal
>   [jgiotta\@magic.local@magic.local] might not be correct.

When this occurs I believe login fails, but terminal only says "System error" at login. At this moment, I'm essentially locked out of my profile and can only access via root.

Comment: _How exactly_ does sss_send_pac fail? There's an infinite number of ways for a program to fail (including making the computer explode); please describe your situation. What domain (AD, IPA, Krb5) do you have? What was done when you "patched" the system? What exact failure did you start seeing?

Comment: I assume you're seeing this in Wireshark. What "name type" is set in the request? The format you show is _normal_ for NT-ENTERPRISE-PRINCIPAL, where the KDC (not the client) is expected to resolve various "UPN suffixes".

Comment: @grawity I've added more detail. Honestly, I don't know if that message is a warning or an error, but it's really the only log I can identify a "failure"

Answer (score 2):

Years late, but for the Internet searchers:

In CentOS 7 as of now (and probably for a while now, really), there is an option in `sssd.conf`:

```
use_fully_qualified_names (bool)
   Use the full name and domain (as formatted by the domain's
   full_name_format) as the user's login name reported to NSS.
```

I was struggling with the duplicated domain name in my kerberos request for xrdp and after a lot of effort learned that explicitly setting this to false even though that's the default made a difference.

**sssd.conf**

```
[domain/magic.local]
use_fully_qualified_names = false
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and adding this fixed it in sssd.conf:

```
[domain/foo.com]
...
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = domain users@dc.example.com
```